# VS2015 - Cordova WebSQL plugin by MSOpenTech - crash with - 'SQLite' is undefined

Tags: cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

```
[Database] name: DBname, lastTransactionId: 0. | new Database(); name = DBname    [Database] name: DBname, lastTransactionId: 0. | Database.open() err = {"description":"'SQLite' is undefined","number":-2146823279,"stack":"ReferenceError: 'SQLite' is undefined   at module.exports.getVersion (ms-appx://AppName/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-websql/src/windows/WebSqlProxy.js:23:13)   at module.exports (ms-appx://AppName/www/cordova.js:901:13)   at callback (ms-appx://AppName/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-websql/www/windows/Database.js:50:9)   at cordova.callbackFromNative (ms-appx://AppName/www/cordova.js:291:41)   at cordova.callbackSuccess (ms-appx://AppName/www/cordova.js:271:9)   at onSuccess (ms-appx://AppName/www/cordova.js:874:17)   at module.exports.open (ms-appx://AppName/www/plugins/cordova-plugin-websql/src/windows/WebSqlProxy.js:66:13)   at module.exports (ms-appx://AppName/www/cordova.js:901:13)   at Database (ms-appx://AppName/www/plugi
```

target: Windows Phone Universal
   db successfully opened or created -----?!?

Answer (score 0):

There's a bug in the version in the repository. Install via Git instead per https://github.com/MSOpenTech/cordova-plugin-websql/issues/29#issuecomment-138943157